# Trying to have everything bold in list

Tags: enumerate, bold

I am trying to get everything inside the \begin{enumerate} bold including the numbers. But I am getting compilation errors

```
\textbf{
\begin{enumerate}
 \item {What git actions does developers do at the beginning and end of an IDE session ?.\\
\item Do developers commit their code after a successful build or test ?\\
\item 
\end{enumerate}
}
```

Comment: you will get an error as you have a spurious `{` after the first `\item` you will also get warnings about the spurious `\\ ` at the end of each item.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `\\`s are required inside list environments and as David said you have a spurious opening brace `{`. Also, since you want only the list be bold, better to add `\bfseries` at the beginning of the list.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}\bfseries
\item What git actions does developers do at the beginning and end of an IDE session?
\item Do developers commit their code after a successful build or test?
\item Forget this ..
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```